# Jenkins Job DSL groovy mangles emoji code points

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

We tried to create a Job with a display name containing a Rocket Emoji with the Jenkins Job-DSL plugin:

```
freeStyleJob(...) {
  ...
  final def disp_name = "+02  Release" // a
  // final def disp_name = "\uD83D\uDE80 Release" // b
  displayName(disp_name)
...
```

Note: [`FreeStyleJob.displayName`](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.displayName)

- Unicode Code Point is `0x1F47D`
- The surrogate pair for this is `\uD83D\uDE80`
- It does not matter whether the source code contains the utf-8 emoji sequence or the surrogate pair escape sequence.

It is possible to inspect the groovy/java string via simple println from withing the Job DSL script.

```
println "job has display_name: $disp_name"
for (int i=0; i<disp_name.length(); ++i) {
    println(sprintf("i $i %08X vs. %04X", java.lang.Character.codePointAt(disp_name, i), (int)disp_name.charAt(i)))
}
```

This shows that the string is reported correctly encoded:

```
job has display_name: +02 ? Release
i 0 0000002B vs. 002B
i 1 00000030 vs. 0030
i 2 00000032 vs. 0032
i 3 00000020 vs. 0020
i 4 0001F680 vs. D83D
i 5 0000DE80 vs. DE80
i 6 00000020 vs. 0020
i 7 00000052 vs. 0052
...
```

(The `?` in the string trace output is to be expected on windows, as we do not currently specify the log output encoding to be UTF8.)

**However** after the Job DSL Job has run successfully, the resulting job will show the following as display name:

```
+02  Release Build
```

That is, the rocket is truncated to `0xF680` which is *not any* meaningful code point, but simply the lower 16 bit of `0001F680`.

We **can** create such a job description in the Jenkins Web UI with no problem.

It seems at some point in the processing from the Job DSL groovy over to the Jenkins internal APIs the characters get truncated to 16bit?

---

Windows, Jenkins 2.263.4 with Job DSL plugin version 1.76

Comment: pretty dated Jenkins version that is... I'd try to see if you can reproduce the issue with the current LTS version, Jenkins migrated to all-things-utf8 with the jdk11 switch somewhen back in 2022.

Comment: try to use html encoded chars: `currentBuild.displayName = "&#x1F680; job name"`

Comment: @daggett - The display name of a Job is not an html field. The escape sequence will show up verbatim on the UI.

Comment: Jenkins 2.319.1 `currentBuild.displayName =  "\uD83D\uDE80 job name"` works well - i see a rocket

Comment: @daggett - I haven't yet gotten around to trying a recent build, but `currentBuild.displayName` - are you talking about the display name of a *build* or of the job itself (-> https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.displayName )